# how to create a kindle newspaper like the The Times

Tags: kindle

I'd like to create a kindle book based on some content I have, but would like to lay it out like the The Times kindle newspaper does it, with the centre button returning to the article list, which itself has a section view on the left, and the relevant articles on the right, changing based on the section changing.

I have no idea where to start on this so I don't have any code yet that I can have reviewed.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at a [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). It has a feature which is called news recipes. Basically it works like: parsing an RSS feed then combine its articles into a magazine (which can be converted to mobipocket too).

You can write your own recipe to convert local HTML files too. Even better, it has a command line interface (`ebook-convert YOUR.RECIPE Your-magazine.mobi`). Recipes are just relatively simple `python` scripts. And the [API](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/news_recipe.html) is rather [well documented](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/news.html#customizing-the-fetch-process).

Answer (score 3):

The Newspaper e-Book style "Contents" page is certainly a special "hypertext" script. The Guardian and Observer e-News use this also. It's a superb device, as one does not have to build a contents page; a standard TOC can fill many "screens" or pages, what a pain to navigate through, or go back to!

I'm not convinced it's a python script? If you use Calibre to manipulate the file, it will most likely remove the active script you would like to see/reuse in projects. The script [phl based on php?] is most likely embedded at the top of the news file or is in a separate file on the Kindle and behaves like JavaScript on a web page. As soon as I find how it's done, I will post an update for you. All e-books as standard should use this device as its VERY much easier to navigate long e-documents.

Comment: I'd much appreciate it if you could post an update when you have more information.